# Fill subsequent values beneath an existing value in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe `df`

I want to populate subsequent values in a column based on the value that preceded it and when I come across another value do the same for that.

So the `dept` column is complete and I can merge this dataset with another to have departments linked info for PIs.

Don't know the best approach, is there a vectorized approach to this our would it require looping, maybe using `iterrows()` or `itertuples()`.

```
data = {"dept": ["Emergency Medicine", "", "", "", "Family Practice", "", ""],
        "pi": [NaN, "Tiger Woods", "Michael Jordan", "Roger Federer", NaN, "Serena Williams", "Alex Morgan"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

        dept                  pi
0       Emergency Medicine  
1                             Tiger Woods
2                             Michael Jordan
3                             Roger Federer
4       Family Practice 
5                             Serena Williams
6                             Alex Morgan
```

```
desired_df

        dept                  pi
0       Emergency Medicine  
1       Emergency Medicine    Tiger Woods
2       Emergency Medicine    Michael Jordan
3       Emergency Medicine    Roger Federer
4       Family Practice 
5       Family Practice       Serena Williams
6       Family Practice       Alex Morgan
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `where` to mask those empty rows with `nan`, then `ffill`

```
# if you have empty strings
mask = df['dept'].ne('')
df['dept'] = df['dept'].where(mask).ffill()

# otherwise, just
# df['dept'] = df['dept'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
                 dept               pi
0  Emergency Medicine              NaN
1  Emergency Medicine      Tiger Woods
2  Emergency Medicine   Michael Jordan
3  Emergency Medicine    Roger Federer
4     Family Practice              NaN
5     Family Practice  Serena Williams
6     Family Practice      Alex Morgan
```

Comment: If you also want to get rid of those rows with pesky `NaN` values in the `pi` column, you can use `df = df.loc[df.pi.notna()]`

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp could I pass a list to this `notna()` if I have added columns that I want to consider with `pi`

Comment: @EoinVaughan `df = df.dropna(subset=['pi', 'pi_1'], how='any')`, modify `subset` and `how` argument to your liking. Also, since `mask` is computed, you can try `df = df[~mask]` as well.

Comment: @QuangHoang brilliant, I needed the `how` argument as `all`. Great approach.